# Angular Lazy Loading Component into HTML template

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I want create a generic component for lazy loading other component

Demo online (click on load button)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7xfwb

this is the code

```
import {
  Component,
  Injector,
  Input,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ViewChild,
  Type,
  createNgModule,
  ComponentRef,
  EventEmitter,
  OnInit,
  NgModule,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-lazy-component',
  template: `
<ng-content *ngIf="isLoading" select="[loading]">
</ng-content>
<ng-content *ngIf="error" select="[error]">
</ng-content>
<ng-container #vcRef></ng-container>
`,
})
export class NgLazyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('vcRef', { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcRef: ViewContainerRef;

  @Input() importModule: () => Promise<Type<any>>;

  _componentInput: Record<string, any>;
  @Input()
  set componentInput(value: Record<string, any>) {
    this._componentInput = value;
    this.setInput();
  }

  _componentOutput: Record<string, EventEmitter<any>>;
  @Input()
  set componentOutput(value: Record<string, EventEmitter<any>>) {
    this._componentOutput = value;
    this.setOutput();
  }

  public isLoading: boolean;
  public error = null;

  private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadModule();
  }

  async loadModule() {
    try {
      this.isLoading = true;
      if (this.componentRef) {
        this.vcRef.clear();
      }
      const module = await this.importModule();
      const lazyModuleRef = createNgModule(module, this.injector);
      if (typeof lazyModuleRef.instance.getComponent !== 'function') {
        throw new Error(
          `${module.name} need to implement getComponent()`
        );
      }
      const component = lazyModuleRef.instance.getComponent();
      this.componentRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(component, {
        ngModuleRef: lazyModuleRef,
      });
      this.setInput();
      this.setOutput();
      this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      this.isLoading = false;
    } catch (err) {
      this.error = err;
      throw err;
    } finally {
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  setInput() {
    if (this.componentRef && this._componentInput) {
      for (const key in this._componentInput) {
        this.componentRef.setInput(key, this._componentInput[key]);
      }
    }
  }

  setOutput() {
    if (this.componentRef && this._componentOutput) {
      for (const key in this._componentOutput) {
        if (!(this.componentRef.instance[key] instanceof EventEmitter)) {
          throw new Error(`@Output() ${key}:EventEmitter - not found!`);
        }
        (this.componentRef.instance[key] as EventEmitter<any>).subscribe(
          (value) => this._componentOutput[key].emit(value)
        );
      }
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [NgLazyComponentComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [NgLazyComponentComponent],
})
export class NgLazyComponentModule {}
```

usage:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { NgLazyComponentModule } from './ng-lazy-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, NgLazyComponentModule],
  template: `
  <button (click)="loaded = false" [disabled]="!loaded">Unload</button> <button (click)="loaded = true" [disabled]="loaded">Load</button>
  <hr>
  <ng-lazy-component [importModule]="importModule" [componentInput]="componentInput" [componentOutput]="componentOutput" *ngIf="loaded"></ng-lazy-component>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public loaded = false;

  public componentInput: Record<string, any> = { testInput: 0 };
  public componentOutput: Record<string, EventEmitter<any>> = {
    testOutput: new EventEmitter<number>(),
  };

  private subComponentOutput: Subscription;

  importModule(): Promise<Type<any>> {
    return import('./test-lazy.module').then((m) => m.TestLazyModule);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subComponentOutput = this.componentOutput.testOutput.subscribe(
      (value) => {
        this.componentInput = {
          ...this.componentInput,
          testInput: value + 1,
        };
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.subComponentOutput) {
      this.subComponentOutput.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

I want some opinions on possible problem of my implementation